# MariaDB doesn't upgrade, 2 versions are installed

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, mariadb

I have a server running on Debian wheezy with MaraiDB and OwnCloud. Few days ago, I wanted to update the packages because of the OwnCloud updates but something went wrong.

Usually in this case I'd probably try to remove and again install the problematic packages, but on a server which is used by different people it doesn't seem like a valid solution anymore.

Here you can see my console output:

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy is installed
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (= 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy is installed
 mariadb-client-10.0 : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (>= 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy is installed
 mariadb-client-core-10.0 : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (>= 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy is installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy is installed
 mariadb-server-core-10.0 : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (>= 10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy) but 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

user@server:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmariadbclient18 mariadb-server-10.0 owncloud
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/37.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,565 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 35901 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libmariadbclient18 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy (using .../libmariadbclient18_10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmariadbclient18 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient18_10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/dialog.so', which is also in package mariadb-server-10.0 10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient18_10.0.5+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried removing the `10.0.4` package version of `libmariadbclient18` but I wasn't really successful in doing that.

So my last hope is here, do you have any ideas how exactly I could fix this issue?

Thx very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem on two of my VPSes this morning. The only way I "fixed" it was to use dpkg to roll back the 10.0.5 packages with the 10.0.4 packages. Not really a fix, but it was the best I could figure out because the usual apt-get install -f did nothing.

dpkg -i /path/to/old/10.0.4 debs

Comment: awesome worked great, the command I used was `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_10.0.4+maria-1~wheezy_all.deb` and everything else worked afterwards again